# Android: ADT Refuses to build without restart

Tags: android, adt

I am trying to build with ADT (on Win7 x64) with Build output set to `verbose` with `target=android-20` (the same error occurs with `normal` console output). I get the following error whenever I try to clean and build

The console shows:

```
[2014-07-31 16:26:07 - MyApp] Removing generated java classes.
[2014-07-31 16:26:07 - MyApp] Starting full Package build.
```

And then does nothing, even after leaving it for a few minutes. Restarting results in a build of all my projects, but then I get the error `AndroidManifest.xml is missing!`. Cleaning and building again at this point result in a successful build and install on my adb device.

I also tried removing `~/.android` to no avail.

Comment: I had this problem once. I had to 1) change my Android Manifest to provoke the regeneration of /gen (adding a whitespace was sufficient) and 2) do a clean/rebuild. Not sure it works all the time though.

Comment: The problem is really that it doesn't build without restart.

Comment: Strange... are you using standard or customized build steps?

Comment: I've got no custom build steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by removing library projects and projects that referenced those libraries from the workspace.